# Find duplicate records where one field is not equal

Tags: mysql

I have a table with user_id, and ip
I want to find records where the ip is identical but the username is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the table to itself in order to find entries where the IP is the same but the username is different. Assuming that your table is called `db.users`, the following query would find all IPs that had more than one user:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `a`.`ip` 
FROM `db`.`users` `a`
INNER JOIN `db`.`users` `b`
ON `a`.`ip` = `b`.`ip`
AND `a`.`user_id` != `b`.`user_id`
```

If you wanted to find a list of all users for such IPs, you could also aggregate with a `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT `a`.`ip`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `a`.`user_id`)
FROM `db`.`users` `a`
INNER JOIN `db`.`users` `b`
ON `a`.`ip` = `b`.`ip`
AND `a`.`user_id` != `b`.`user_id`
GROUP BY `a`.`ip`
```

You can play around with this on this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b987f/2) to get closer to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query ;

```
   select distinct t.user_id, t.ip 
   from table t inner join table x
   on t.user_id <> x.user_id and t.ip=x.ip;
```

Comment: I think I may have been too sketchy but I really am unsure how to word this!

Comment: There is one table with both the above fields, the one table contains lots of entries that are... Username......Ip.....where the username is repeated many times and so is the ip. I am trying to find if two usernames are using the same ip? The query above results in a syntax error